# How to push data into highchart with just one decimal place?

Tags: javascript, highcharts, floating-point, trigonometry

I´m trying to make sinus and cosinus graphs. There are pushed data like this:

```
data: (function exp() {
                var data1 = [],
                    //i = 0,
                    x = 0,
                    y = 0;

                for (i = -10; i <= 10; i = i + 0.1) {
                    //x = i.toFixed(4);
                    x = i;
                    y = Math.sin(i);
                    data1.push({
                        //x: Math.round(i * 10000)/10000,
                        x: x,
                        y: y,
                    });
                    if ((y.toFixed(4) == 0) || (y.toFixed(4) == -0)) {
                        //var x = Math.sin(Math.round(i * 10000)/10000);
                        //var y = Math.round(Math.sin(i) * 10000)/10000;
                        addtext(x, y);
                    }
                }
                return data1;
        })()
    },
```

So there should be x values: -10; -9.9; -9.8, -9.7 and so on...But if you look at graph(http://jsfiddle.net/K5Zhr/4/), there are x values: -10; -9.9; -9.8, and then there is **-9.700000000000001** and all next x values are screwed up in same way.

I have tried to use methods *.toFixed* and *.toPrecision*, but they (for example) made point[0, sin(0)] to be something like [-0.0000, -0.0000], what is of course bad, becuse it takes x value -0.000000000000187...
Could anybody help me to push just data with 1 decimal place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't try to adjust the input x values, [that's just how computers store numbers](http://floating-point-gui.de/).

To show rounded or floored numbers in the tooltip, you'll need to drop the `footerFormat`, `headerFormat`, and `pointFormat` and take complete control of the tooltip using the [formatter](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip.formatter) option.  Something like this:

```
       formatter: function() {
            var s = '<b>'+ Highcharts.numberFormat(this.x,1) +'</b>';                
            $.each(this.points, function(i, point) {
                s += '<br/>'+ point.series.name +': '+
                    Highcharts.numberFormat(this.point.y,4);
            });
            return s;
        }
```

Should get you want you need.  Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/K5Zhr/7/).